# Find the perimeter of the triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

There is a triangle $ABC$. A line bisects the angle at the vertex $A$ and cuts the side $BC$ in point $D$ such that $BD=9$ and $DC=12$. If $O$ is the center of the circle that is inscribed inside the triangle $ABC$ and $AO:OD=4:3$, find the perimeter of the triangle $ABC$.

This seems very hard to me.

edit: I even drew one bad picture of this problem:

[image: picture]

Comment: A picture would be nice

Comment: @lhf Here it comes.

Comment: Your attempts? The bisector theorem gives many informations.

Comment: @lhf [Here](https://imgur.com/R2N4Acn). I'm sorry, but I couldn't position $O$ at the center of the circle. Just keep that in mind, and otherwise I think it's a good "approximation".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio None. I'm not familiar with such a theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $AO$ is a bisector of $\Delta ADC$, we obtain:$$\frac{AC}{DC}=\frac{AO}{OD}$$ or
$$\frac{AC}{12}=\frac{4}{3},$$ which gives $AC=16$.

Now, since $AD$ is a bisector of $\Delta ABC$, we obtain: $$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BD}{DC}$$ or
$$\frac{AB}{16}=\frac{9}{12},$$
which gives $AB=12$ and the perimeter is $$21+16+12=49.$$

Comment: Hello. Can you please explain why is $\frac{AC}{DC}=\frac{AO}{OD}$ (not in the comments, it would be better to edit the answer)? I thought that I understand it but it turned out that my understanding was wrong.

Comment: @Hanlon I added something. See now.

Comment: I don't see how $AO$ is a bisector of $\triangle ADC$ (at least not from my picture). It's obviously a part of the side $AD$.

Comment: $O$ is a center of the inscribed circle of $\Delta ABC$,, which is a common point of the triangle bisectors. Yes, your picture is not good.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to give the complete answer, but enough so that you can solve this yourself.

1. You already know BC (=BD+DC). So, you need to find AB and AC to find perimeter.
2. [Angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) should give you the ratio of AB:AC
3. The incenter divides AD in the ratio (AB+AC):BC.

(2) and (3) should give you the 2 equations for your to solve the problem.